# jQuery: wrap every nth word in a span

Tags: jquery, string

Is it possible in jquery to wrap each nth word in a span

so lets say I have the html string

```
<h3>great Prices great Service</h3>
```

this will be wrapped as follows ( each 2nd word )

```
<h3>great <span>Prices</span> great <span>Service</span></h3>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var h3 = $('h3');
var text = h3.text().split(' ');

for( var i = 1, len = text.length; i < len; i=i+2 ) {
    text[i] = '<span>' + text[i] + '</span>';
}
h3.html(text.join(' '));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H5zzq/

or

```
var h3 = $('h3');
var text = h3.text().split(' ');

$.each(text,function(i,val) {
    if( i % 2) {
        text[i] = '<span>' + val + '</span>';
    }
});
h3.html(text.join(' '));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H5zzq/1

---

To deal with `&` as you requested in your comment, I created an `offset` variable that is incremented whenever one is encountered.

```
var h3 = $('h3');
var text = h3.text().split(' ');
var offset = 0;

for( var i = 1, len = text.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    if( text[i] === '&' ) {
        offset++;
    } else if( (i-offset) % 2 ) {
        text[i] = '<span>' + text[i] + '</span>';
    }
}
h3.html(text.join(' '));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H5zzq/3

Comment: Exactly the way I was doing it: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/buNYU/). +1 :)

Comment: Very nice I can work with this just one thing extra is it possible that if the nth word is a "&" then the word after the "&" is wrapped

Comment: @nokiko: You're saying that you want to exclude `&` from the count?

Comment: yes if the "&" is a seperate word than it should be excluded.

Comment: @nokiko: I updated my answer so that the `&` is not considered when determining every second word.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by first getting the text of the `<h3>` element, then split the string to an array, cycle through the array in a `for` loop, and whenever your iterator `i` is even, add `span` tags to the current word. Then, just rebuild the string and insert it as the `text` property of your `<h3>` tag.