# Is there a way to add a class to the first word of a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm looking for a way to add a custom class to the first and second word of a specific class ?

My code goes like this

```
<h2 class="content-heading">Latest News</h2>
```

And i would like to have something like

```
<h2 class="content-heading"><span class="1">Latest</span> <span class="2">News</span></h2>
```

Comment: I didnt get your idea.. because I was actually going to tell you about spans but you alredy did it...

Comment: Friendly Warning, all the answers (so far) may or may not not handle <h2 class="content-heading">Latest <strong>News</strong></h2> as you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the `html` using a function then `split` the `innerText` and `map` to a `span`.

```js
$('.content-heading').html(function() {
  return this.innerText.split(' ').map(function(e, i) {
    return $('<span />', {
      class: 'i' + i,
      text: e
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.i0 {
  color:red;  
}

.i1{
   color:blue; 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="content-heading">Latest News</h2>
```

**NOTE**: classes need to be SGML names. Therefore I have prefixed with an `i` in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
var t = $(".content-heading").text();
t = t.replace(/.*?\s/, function (v) {
    return "<span class='class1'>" + v + "</span>";
});
$(".content-heading").html(t);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j97skLnL/)

Answer (score 0):

You already did it with `<span>` tags but you need to use characters not numbers for the classes. Just replace `1` and `2` with letters and access them in css and thats it

```
<h2 class="content-heading"><span class="h">Latest</span> <span class="f">News</span></h2>


.h{
  color: red;
}
.f{
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this autonomously with `javascript` if that is the type of answer you're looking for, check this out.

This will wrap your variable of `word` in a `<span>` with the class `first-word`.

```
$('.content-heading').each(function() {
   var html = $(this).html();
   var word = html.substr(0, html.indexOf(" "));
   var rest = html.substr(html.indexOf(" "));
   $(this).html(rest).prepend($("<span/>").html(word).addClass("first-word"));
});
```

Here is a **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xu645ekw/2/)** example.

Answer (score 0):

It could go like this:

```
var h2 = $('h2');
var text = h2.text().split(' ');

for( var i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) {
text[i] = '<span class="class'+i+'">' + text[i] + '</span>';
}
h2.html(text.join(' '));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H5zzq/

(I stole this answer from [jQuery: wrap every nth word in a span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994408/jquery-wrap-every-nth-word-in-a-span))

Comment: Oh I didn't even think of using `nth` to find the words. Good choice.